# Alan Juden .NET Core Report Viewer Working in localhost but not in Production

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am implementing [Alan Juden's MVC Report Viewer](https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer) and running into some issues when I deploy my project to production.

I have set up the report viewer in my .NET Core app and everything is working fine in localhost, but when I deploy to production and try to load the report I get this message in my page where the report should render: `Report failed to load, check report parameters...`

When I open the browser developer tools under the Network tab I can see the **ViewReportPage** method is not being found, thus returning a status code of 404

```
Request URL: https://MYDOMAIN/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=%2FGearUpAlumni%2FAlumniData&page=1&
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

So the issues is not that the report is expecting a parameter (again, works fine in localhost), but that is not *finding* **ViewReportPage** method in my `ReportController` class.

This particular method (`ViewReportPage`) is being implemented by `AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.ReportController`, which is inherited in my controller.

Have anyone ran into a similar issue? or maybe know how to approach this to fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Since my app is deployed to a subdirectory within the domain I needed to change the JavaScript to include the base path.

So basically from

```
$.get("Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)
```

To

```
@{ 
    string pathBase = Context.Request.PathBase;
}
...
...
$.get("@pathBase/Report/ViewReportPage/?reportPath=@Model.ReportPath.UrlEncode()&page=" + page + "&" + urlParams)
```

Now the report works fine in localhost and production and is calling the correct URL

```
https://MYDOMAIN/SUBDIRECTORY/Report/ViewReportPage/reportPath=%2FGearUpAlumni%2FAlumniData&page=1&
```